# Channels app stops working without any reason unitil ASGI server restart

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

At some point in time application server stops working. WS-clients are trying to connect but they can't. There are tracebacks in the logfile, that client is disconnected before connection is accepted. Server stops even serve plain HTTP reqests(without any tracebacks in the logfile).

I have a channels app to work with o7sock.js(https://github.com/Z-Wave-Me/O7) on the one hand and REST Framework(DRF) on the other hand. Everything works fine for some time. I see ping/pong in the logfile and reports from ws-clients. I also can make REST calls against API.

At some point clients are disconnected at once. It looks like there were ping/pong messages and the next ping request ends with traceback, because client is disconnected. After that point there are only connection requests from ws-clients, that are disconnected before connection is accepted. HTTP/REST interface is not available at this time.

The only way to deal with it at this moment is to restart ASGI server program.
I have tried daphne and uvicorn - both have this issue.

My app has one WebsocketConsumer (synchronous) to deal with WS-clients. I have also some other SyncConsumers, that are working in worker processes.

The main problem is that time to fail is not regular, so i can't figure out the main cause of the problem. It also looks like the worker processes are not affected, because i need to restart only ASGI server to make app working.

I want to have WS server with long living clients. Server should work with django models and provide REST API for external services(mobile app). Now i have a server that is working for some time, but can fail at any time without any reason.

Forgot to mention, that I use almost last versions of libraries and frameworks, available via pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i've managed it by myself. For those, who can run in this issue:
it's all about default settings. Using Sync consumers leaves you with 5 threads per CPU for simultaneous requests, no matter if it is WS or HTTP. As it is stated in the docs https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html you can bump this limit with env variable ASGI_THREADS. But generally, it's better to use Async consumer for long-living WS-clients. Now i'm out of time for refactoring, so the solution is to run several( one per CPU) daphne servers on shared FD with ASGI_THREADS=100. This gives 400 threads with 4 daphne processes for synchronous tasks. Anyway, I'm going to rewrite my WS consumer to be async early next year.
With settings above I don't see any problem or warning in my logs for more than a day.